# Aumentar tamanho de uma DIV manualmente

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma `div` com uma lista de itens dentro, gostaria de saber como faço uma função para que quando o usuário clique em outra `div` abaixo  da lista, ele consiga redimensionar a altura dessa `div` manualmente (o próprio Stack Overflow tem esse sistema, quando você vai criar uma pergunta.

Acho que é mais fácil de entender com um exemplo: http://jsbin.com/bokusovuba

Quando o usuário clicar naquela barra mais escura e puxar para cima ou para baixo a `div` deveria ser redimensionada...

Como posso fazer isso usando apenas Javascript puro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, para fazer isso com JS nativo tem de dar alguns passos.

Por ordem será:

- Amarrar oscultador de evento para mousedown
- amarrar oscultador de evento para mousemove
- fazer a barra ter position: absolute
- dar a posição top igual à posição do rato
- calcular a coordenada do canto do `ul`
- calcular a diferença entre essa coordenada e a posição do rato
- dar a altura da div essa diferença.

Em código isso pode ser assim:

```
window.onload = addListeners;

function addListeners(){
    document.querySelector('.resize').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp(){
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e){
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e){
  var div = document.querySelector('.resize');
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';

  var altura = div.previousElementSibling.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  div.previousElementSibling.style.height = (e.clientY - altura) + 'px';
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsbin.com/kukocuqoqo/1/

Comment: Perfeito amigo, só poderia me esclarecer o que é oscultador?

Comment: @wag oscultador = "escutador" = listener

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Vai ser de grande utilidade